# Using @SecondaryTables to display all data from beers table, categories table and styles table

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to display all data objects from the beers table in a list, and in the drill down, to display all beers data with their corresponding category name from the category table and their corresponding style name from the style table, it gets these results from the beer table style id and category id columns.

I've tried using the @SecondaryTables annotation as shown but in the list of beers it only displays 10 beers and that is the number of category names so it is messing up how it is being mapped.
the following is my attempt at doing this.

This is what I have added to the JPA class, what is the correct solution to this.

```
 @Table(name = "beers")
        @SecondaryTables({
        @SecondaryTable(name = "categories"),
        @SecondaryTable(name = "styles")})


@Column(table = "categories", name = "cat_name")
private String catName;

@Column(table = "styles", name = "style_name")
private String styleName;



  public String getCatName() {
        return catName;
    }

    public void setCatName(String catName) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

    public String getStyleName() {
        return styleName;
    }

    public void setStyleName(String styleName) {
        this.styleName = styleName;
    }
```

here is a picture of the tables in an ER diagram
[image]

here is the beers.java JPA for extra reference

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "beers")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name = "categories"),
    @SecondaryTable(name = "styles")})
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByLikeName", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.name LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%')"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByBreweryId", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.breweryId = :breweryId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByName", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByCatId", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.catId = :catId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByStyleId", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.styleId = :styleId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByAbv", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.abv = :abv"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByIbu", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.ibu = :ibu"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findBySrm", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.srm = :srm"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByAddUser", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.addUser = :addUser"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByLastMod", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.lastMod = :lastMod"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByBuyPrice", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.buyPrice = :buyPrice"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findBySellPrice", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.sellPrice = :sellPrice")})
public class Beers implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "brewery_id")
    private int breweryId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "cat_id")
    private int catId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "style_id")
    private int styleId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "abv")
    private float abv;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ibu")
    private float ibu;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "srm")
    private float srm;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "add_user")
    private int addUser;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_mod")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastMod;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "buy_price")
    private double buyPrice;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sell_price")
    private double sellPrice;

    @Column(table = "categories", name = "cat_name")
    private String catName;

    @Column(table = "styles", name = "style_name")
    private String styleName;

    public String getCatName() {
        return catName;
    }

    public void setCatName(String catName) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

    public String getStyleName() {
        return styleName;
    }

    public void setStyleName(String styleName) {
        this.styleName = styleName;
    }

    public Beers() {
    }

    public Beers(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Beers(Integer id, int breweryId, String name, int catId, int styleId, float abv, float ibu, float srm, String description, int addUser, Date lastMod, String image, double buyPrice, double sellPrice, String catName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.breweryId = breweryId;
        this.name = name;
        this.catId = catId;
        this.styleId = styleId;
        this.abv = abv;
        this.ibu = ibu;
        this.srm = srm;
        this.description = description;
        this.addUser = addUser;
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
        this.image = image;
        this.buyPrice = buyPrice;
        this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
          this.catName = catName;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBreweryId() {
        return breweryId;
    }

    public void setBreweryId(int breweryId) {
        this.breweryId = breweryId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }

    public void setCatId(int catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }

    public int getStyleId() {
        return styleId;
    }

    public void setStyleId(int styleId) {
        this.styleId = styleId;
    }

    public float getAbv() {
        return abv;
    }

    public void setAbv(float abv) {
        this.abv = abv;
    }

    public float getIbu() {
        return ibu;
    }

    public void setIbu(float ibu) {
        this.ibu = ibu;
    }

    public float getSrm() {
        return srm;
    }

    public void setSrm(float srm) {
        this.srm = srm;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getAddUser() {
        return addUser;
    }

    public void setAddUser(int addUser) {
        this.addUser = addUser;
    }

    public Date getLastMod() {
        return lastMod;
    }

    public void setLastMod(Date lastMod) {
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public double getBuyPrice() {
        return buyPrice;
    }

    public void setBuyPrice(double buyPrice) {
        this.buyPrice = buyPrice;
    }

    public double getSellPrice() {
        return sellPrice;
    }

    public void setSellPrice(double sellPrice) {
        this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Beers)) {
            return false;
        }
        Beers other = (Beers) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "brewery.src.model.Beers[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

below is my attempt at using @manytoone annotation

```
Beers.java


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "beers")


    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByLikeName", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.name LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%')"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByBreweryId", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.breweryId = :breweryId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByName", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.name = :name"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByCatId", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.catId = :catId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByStyleId", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.styleId = :styleId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByAbv", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.abv = :abv"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByIbu", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.ibu = :ibu"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findBySrm", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.srm = :srm"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByAddUser", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.addUser = :addUser"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByLastMod", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.lastMod = :lastMod"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByBuyPrice", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.buyPrice = :buyPrice"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findBySellPrice", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.sellPrice = :sellPrice")})
    public class Beers implements Serializable {
      @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name="styleId")
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "brewery_id")
        private int breweryId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "cat_id")
        private int catId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "style_id")
        private int styleId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "abv")
        private float abv;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "ibu")
        private float ibu;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "srm")
        private float srm;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Lob
        @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
        @Column(name = "description")
        private String description;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "add_user")
        private int addUser;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "last_mod")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date lastMod;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Lob
        @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
        @Column(name = "image")
        private String image;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "buy_price")
        private double buyPrice;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "sell_price")
        private double sellPrice;

        @Column(table = "categories", name = "cat_name")
        private String catName;

        @Column(table = "styles", name = "style_name")
        private String styleName;


        public Beers() {
        }

        public Beers(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Beers(Integer id, int breweryId, String name, int catId, int styleId, float abv, float ibu, float srm, String description, int addUser, Date lastMod, String image, double buyPrice, double sellPrice) {
            this.id = id;
            this.breweryId = breweryId;
            this.name = name;
            this.catId = catId;
            this.styleId = styleId;
            this.abv = abv;
            this.ibu = ibu;
            this.srm = srm;
            this.description = description;
            this.addUser = addUser;
            this.lastMod = lastMod;
            this.image = image;
            this.buyPrice = buyPrice;
            this.sellPrice = sellPrice;


        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getBreweryId() {
            return breweryId;
        }

        public void setBreweryId(int breweryId) {
            this.breweryId = breweryId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getCatId() {
            return catId;
        }

        public void setCatId(int catId) {
            this.catId = catId;
        }

        public int getStyleId() {
            return styleId;
        }

        public void setStyleId(int styleId) {
            this.styleId = styleId;
        }

        public float getAbv() {
            return abv;
        }

        public void setAbv(float abv) {
            this.abv = abv;
        }

        public float getIbu() {
            return ibu;
        }

        public void setIbu(float ibu) {
            this.ibu = ibu;
        }

        public float getSrm() {
            return srm;
        }

        public void setSrm(float srm) {
            this.srm = srm;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getAddUser() {
            return addUser;
        }

        public void setAddUser(int addUser) {
            this.addUser = addUser;
        }

        public Date getLastMod() {
            return lastMod;
        }

        public void setLastMod(Date lastMod) {
            this.lastMod = lastMod;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public double getBuyPrice() {
            return buyPrice;
        }

        public void setBuyPrice(double buyPrice) {
            this.buyPrice = buyPrice;
        }

        public double getSellPrice() {
            return sellPrice;
        }

        public void setSellPrice(double sellPrice) {
            this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
        }
           public String getCatName() {
            return catName;
        }

        public void setCatName(String catName) {
            this.catName = catName;
        }

        public String getStyleName() {
            return styleName;
        }

        public void setStyleName(String styleName) {
            this.styleName = styleName;
        }


        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 0;
            hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
            if (!(object instanceof Beers)) {
                return false;
            }
            Beers other = (Beers) object;
            if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "brewery.src.model.Beers[ id=" + id + " ]";
        }
```

catgories.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categories.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Categories c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categories.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Categories c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categories.findByCatName", query = "SELECT c FROM Categories c WHERE c.catName = :catName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categories.findByLastMod", query = "SELECT c FROM Categories c WHERE c.lastMod = :lastMod")})
public class Categories implements Serializable {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "beer")
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "cat_name")
    private String catName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_mod")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastMod;

    public Categories() {
    }

    public Categories(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Categories(Integer id, String catName, Date lastMod) {
        this.id = id;
        this.catName = catName;
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCatName() {
        return catName;
    }

    public void setCatName(String catName) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

    public Date getLastMod() {
        return lastMod;
    }

    public void setLastMod(Date lastMod) {
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Categories)) {
            return false;
        }
        Categories other = (Categories) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "brewery.src.model.Categories[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

styles.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "styles")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Styles.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Styles s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Styles.findById", query = "SELECT s FROM Styles s WHERE s.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Styles.findByCatId", query = "SELECT s FROM Styles s WHERE s.catId = :catId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Styles.findByStyleName", query = "SELECT s FROM Styles s WHERE s.styleName = :styleName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Styles.findByLastMod", query = "SELECT s FROM Styles s WHERE s.lastMod = :lastMod")})
public class Styles implements Serializable {
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="catId")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "beer")
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "cat_id")
    private int catId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "style_name")
    private String styleName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_mod")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastMod;

    public Styles() {
    }

    public Styles(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Styles(Integer id, int catId, String styleName, Date lastMod) {
        this.id = id;
        this.catId = catId;
        this.styleName = styleName;
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }

    public void setCatId(int catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }

    public String getStyleName() {
        return styleName;
    }

    public void setStyleName(String styleName) {
        this.styleName = styleName;
    }

    public Date getLastMod() {
        return lastMod;
    }

    public void setLastMod(Date lastMod) {
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Styles)) {
            return false;
        }
        Styles other = (Styles) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "brewery.src.model.Styles[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

500 error root cause

```
Exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    brewery.src.controller.beerService.getAllBeers(beerService.java:26)
    brewery.src.controller.beerController.getBeers(beerController.java:39)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)


Root Cause
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [taste_PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [categories] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(brewery.src.model.Beers --> [DatabaseTable(beers)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(brewery.src.model.Beers --> [DatabaseTable(beers)])
```

Comment: if in `categories` there are ten entries, how can there be more beers? I feel you misinterpret categories as a "normalized table"/association of beers, that's wrong/not what `SecodaryTable` means...

Comment: ...and the column `beers.cat_id` suggests: Many (beers) ToOne (category) (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne)

Comment: ..whereas a secondary table is 1-to-1 (to the primary)

Comment: With SecondaryTable you modeled it like: `beers:1<->1:styles:1<->1:categories` ...but columns *and* the problem description suggest rather: `beers:N<->1:styles:N<->1:categories`

Comment: @xerx593 I've never used many to one annotation yet, is the way to do it, have a many to one and join column annotation in the beer table to styles table like in the link you sent and then have another many to one and join column annotation in the styles table to the categories table?

Comment: exactly right, @GreyWolf18 (with little "degree of freedom": map (directly...or "navigate via association) beers <-> categories ? ...and other details) most tutorials show only "one level" of association, but you can extend/apply to multiple ... (google.comq?=jpa+many2one) (*and/but*: I never heard of `SecondaryTables`before! ..thx for the incentive:)

Comment: @xerx593 i have added the many to one annotation but i am getting a 500 error, i have edited my question to include the JPA that i have used and 500 error root cause, could you examine what i have done wrong?